# IPad Safari touch events

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Which all touch events are provided or detected by Mobile Safari browser in IPad?

Basically what all does webkit provide?

I am kind of looking for the native app (IOS SDK) equivalent of touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc.. in Safari..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project handles it brilliantly, used it myself.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/

View it on an iDevice.

Answer (score 7):

Both iOS and Android browsers support touchStart, touchEnd and touchMove: http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html

Detecting multitouch events seems to be possible on iOS:
http://www.html5rocks.com/mobile/touch.html

And if you prefer jQuery, there is jQuery mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/events.html

Comment: I guess you missed the bit about **native app (IOS SDK) equivalent**. Unless jQuery is releasing native iOS libraries now.

Comment: If I need to implement a drag/drop functionality on iPad (similar to http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable), will jQuery mobile library help and is it free for commercial use? Also what other options I have to implement drag/drop on iPad?

Answer (score 6):

All mobile safari events, per Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html